# Spring Security doesn't differentiate roles

Tags: java, spring, spring-security

I am doing basic authentication using Spring Security using `DaoAuthenticationProvider`. I want to preauthorize my requests, so I am using the `@PreAuthorize` annotation. The problem is that it appears that Spring Security doesn't differentiate between multiple roles and authorities. For example, if I access `/users`, I am being prompted to the login screen, but no matter what user I login with, I always get the list of all users displayed. This is not what I want to achieve I want to restrict access to users list to the role admin.

Here is my `SecurityConfig`:

```java
@Configuration
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(securedEnabled = true)
@RequiredArgsConstructor(onConstructor = @__({@Autowired}))
public class SecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    @Resource(name = "userRestClient")
    UserService userService;

    @Autowired
    private AuthenticationProvider authenticationProvider;

    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("authenticationProvider")
    public void setAuthenticationProvider(AuthenticationProvider authenticationProvider) {
        this.authenticationProvider = authenticationProvider;
    }

    @Autowired
    public void configureAuthManager(AuthenticationManagerBuilder authenticationManagerBuilder) {
        authenticationManagerBuilder.authenticationProvider(authenticationProvider);
    }

    @Bean
    public DaoAuthenticationProvider authenticationProvider() {
        DaoAuthenticationProvider authProvider = new DaoAuthenticationProvider();
        authProvider.setUserDetailsService(userService);
        // authProvider.setPasswordEncoder(encoder());
        return authProvider;
    }

    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder encoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder(11);
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity httpSecurity) throws Exception {
        httpSecurity
            .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/", "/users", "/user").permitAll()
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and()
            .formLogin()
                .loginPage("/login")
                .permitAll()
                .and()
            .logout().permitAll();
        httpSecurity
            .csrf().disable();
        httpSecurity
            .headers()
                .frameOptions().disable();
    }

    @Bean
    protected UserDetailsService userDetailsService() {
        return super.userDetailsService();
    }
}
```

Here is my Controller:

```java
@Controller
@Component
public class UserWebController {

    private final UserRestClient userService = new UserRestClient();

    @PreAuthorize("hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN')")
    @RequestMapping(value = "/users", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public ResponseEntity<List<User>> getAllUsers() {
        List<User> users = userService.findAllUsers().stream().map(UserMapper.INSTANCE::from).collect(Collectors.toList());
        return new ResponseEntity<List<User>>(users, HttpStatus.OK);
    }
}
```

My implementation of the `UserDetails` interface:

```
public class MyUser implements UserDetails {

    private User user;

    public MyUser(User user) {
        this.user = user;
    }

    @Override
    public Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> getAuthorities() {

        Set<GrantedAuthority> roles = new HashSet<>();
        roles.add(new Authority(user.getRole()));
        return roles;
    }

    @Override
    public String getPassword() {
        return user.getPassword();
    }

    @Override
    public String getUsername() {
        return user.getUsername();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isAccountNonExpired() {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isAccountNonLocked() {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isCredentialsNonExpired() {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isEnabled() {
        return true;
    }
}
```

User entity:

```
@Table(name = "users")
@AllArgsConstructor
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@javax.persistence.Entity
public class User extends Entity implements Serializable {

    @Column(name = "username")
    private String username;

    @Column(name = "password")
    private String password;

    @Column(name = "role")
    private String role;
}
```

Comment: @dur my understanding of the PreAuthorize annotation is that I will get OK response only if the user is authenticated with the correct roles. So in my case, if an authenticated user isn't  Admin, i don't want them to get the list of users.

Comment: @dur Sorry, it's my first question here, I'll try to improve next time. Your answer seems to be the solution, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You have to enable `@PreAuthorize`, see [`EnableGlobalMethodSecurity#prePostEnabled`](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/apidocs/org/springframework/security/config/annotation/method/configuration/EnableGlobalMethodSecurity.html#prePostEnabled--):

> Determines if Spring Security's pre post annotations should be enabled. Default is false.

Your modified and simplified configuration:

```java
@Configuration
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true, securedEnabled = true)
@RequiredArgsConstructor(onConstructor = @__({@Autowired}))
public class SecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    @Resource(name = "userRestClient")
    UserService userService;

    @Autowired
    private AuthenticationProvider authenticationProvider;

    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("authenticationProvider")
    public void setAuthenticationProvider(AuthenticationProvider authenticationProvider) {
        this.authenticationProvider = authenticationProvider;
    }

    @Autowired
    public void configureAuthManager(AuthenticationManagerBuilder authenticationManagerBuilder) {
        authenticationManagerBuilder.authenticationProvider(authenticationProvider);
    }

    @Bean
    public DaoAuthenticationProvider authenticationProvider() {
        DaoAuthenticationProvider authProvider = new DaoAuthenticationProvider();
        authProvider.setUserDetailsService(userService);
        return authProvider;
    }

    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder encoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder(11);
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity httpSecurity) throws Exception {
        httpSecurity
            .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/", "/users", "/user").permitAll()
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and()
            .formLogin()
                .loginPage("/login")
                .permitAll()
                .and()
            .logout()
                .permitAll()
                .and()
            .csrf()
                .disable()
                .and()
            .headers()
                .frameOptions().disable();
    }

    @Bean
    protected UserDetailsService userDetailsService() {
        return super.userDetailsService();
    }
}
```