# Permission based access control in spring

Tags: java, spring, spring-security, rbac

im trying to secure my endpoints with role based access control. I have implemented the whole structure as well as CustomUserDetailService, however im not sure how should i enforce these rules on enpoints, i was looking for some nice annotation based evaluation like `@PreAuthorize(hasRole('role'))`. My structure looks follwoing:

Permission:

```
@Entity
public class Permission implements GrantedAuthority {

@Id
private Long id;

@Column(name = "NAME")
private String name;

@ManyToMany(mappedBy = "permissions",  fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
private Collection<Role> roles;

@Override
public String getAuthority() {
    return name;
}
```

Role:

```
@Entity
public class Role implements GrantedAuthority {

@Id @Column(name="ID" )
private Long id;

@Column(name="NAME", nullable=false , unique=false)
private String name;

@ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinTable(
        name = "role_x_permission",
        joinColumns = @JoinColumn(
                name = "role_id"),
        inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(
                name = "permission_id"))
private List<Permission> permissions;

@Override
public String getAuthority() {
    return name;
}
```

User:

```
@Entity(name = "User")
@Table(name = "USERS")
@Data
public class User {

@Id
private Long id;

@Column(name="LOGIN"   , nullable=true , unique=false)
private String login;

@Column(name="PASSWORD"   , nullable=false , unique=false)
private String password;

@ManyToMany( fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinTable(name = "USER_ROLES",
        joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "user_id"),
        inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "role_id"))
private Set<Role> roles;
```

Now i have defined my CustomUserDetailsService:

```
@Service
public class UserDetailsServiceImpl implements UserDetailsService {

@Autowired
private UserRepository userRepository;


@Override
@Transactional
public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String username) throws UsernameNotFoundException {
    User applicationUser = userRepository.findByUsername(username);
    if (applicationUser.getId() == null) {
        throw new UsernameNotFoundException(username);
    }
    return new org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User(applicationUser.getLogin(), applicationUser.getPassword(),
            getAuthorities(applicationUser.getRoles()));
}

@Transactional
public Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> getUserAuthorities(String username) {
    User user = userRepository.findByUsername(username);

    return getAuthorities(user.getRoles());
}

private Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> getAuthorities(
        Collection<Role> roles) {

    return getGrantedAuthorities(getPermissions(roles));
}

private List<String> getPermissions(Collection<Role> roles) {

    List<String> permissions = new ArrayList<>();
    List<Permission> collection = new ArrayList<>();
    for (Role role : roles) {
        collection.addAll(role.getPermissions());
    }
    for (Permission item : collection) {
        permissions.add(item.getName());
    }
    return permissions;
}

private List<GrantedAuthority> getGrantedAuthorities(List<String> permissions) {
    List<GrantedAuthority> authorities = new ArrayList<>();
    for (String permission : permissions) {
        authorities.add(new SimpleGrantedAuthority(permission));
    }
    return authorities;
}
}
```

Then i'm trying to annotate my endpoint with @PreAuthorize

```
@PostMapping("/doSomething")
@PreAuthorize("hasRole('doSomething')")
public SomeEntity createComment(@RequestBody SomeEntity something) {
   ...
}
```

I have user with role of `USER`, this role doesn't have permission to `doSomething`, however it seems like `@PreAuthorize("hasRole('doSomething')")` is not working. I'm not sure what i have done wrong, coule you please point my mistake?

Also, since im using `RBAC` this `hasRole` is very missleading since access is permission based, not role based.

What would be correct way to authorize access to endpoint with `RBAC` approach?

Comment: *Also, since im using RBAC this hasRole is very missleading since access is permission based, not role based.* That is confusing, because RBAC means *Role Based Access Control* and `hasRole` is the right way to implement it. However, you also not using permissions, because permissions (Spring wording) is part of [ACL](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#domain-acls).

Comment: @dur lets assume that for now that Permission is only for RBAC in my case. If i understood RBAC properly, each enpoint can have a permission, and the a role has set of permissions. Then hasRole needs to refer to permission correct?

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44004977/spring-security-doesnt-differentiate-roles

Answer (score 0):

You should use `hasAuthority('doSomething')` instead of `hasRole('doSomething')`.

Role is just a permission with a prefix `Role_`.

So `hasRole('XXX')` is same as `hasAuthority('ROLE_XXX')`

Comment: this did not solve the problem, user is still able to ``doSomrthing``